# React Native And Flask Sessions Compatibility Question

Tags: python, reactjs, react-native, flask, mobile

This is more of a simple question. Flask sessions (Redis) and react.js work very well with each other. You can store/save information in the flask session such as user information and/or preferences. I am currently working on a website that uses said flask sessions. From what Ive read online so far, this method will not work with react native. Which will force me to revamp some stuff since both the web and the app will connect to the same server.

**So my question is, is there really no way to make flask sessions work with react native?** I understand my alternatives are tokens, but i want to make sure this is method impossible before I start making a V2 of my server. Feel free to provide some example code if it makes explaining it easier.